# Pseudoinverse different results in R, C and Python

Tags: python, c, r, numpy

I'm translating an algorithm from R to C, I need to obtain the pseudoinverse of a matrix but the result I get in C has some differences with the one I get in R. These differences change the behaviour of the algorithm.

The code I used to get the pseudoinverse in C is [this](https://gist.github.com/turingbirds/5e99656e08dbe1324c99).

I did some reading and there are different ways to get the pseudoinverse, the method used in C is Moore-Penrose. The function used in R is from the library [corpcor](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/corpcor/versions/1.6.9/topics/pseudoinverse). Both use "Singular Value Decomposition".

This is the matrix from which I want to get the pseudoinverse

```
1                  0.920980394593472  0.996160973582776   0.996772980609752   0.997372221594439 0.999972797627027
0.920980394593472  1                  0.885601439824631   0.88878682654952    0.892173764646865 0.923738536637407
0.996160973582776  0.885601439824631  1                   0.999973383442349   0.999885329646229 0.99549326808266
0.996772980609752  0.88878682654952   0.999973383442349   1                   0.999969202115456 0.996158288591094
0.997372221594439  0.892173764646865  0.999885329646229   0.999969202115456   1                 0.996814694067663
0.999972797627027  0.923738536637407  0.99549326808266    0.996158288591094   0.996814694067663 1
```

The results I get from the function pseudoinverse() in R is:

```
1398676681.0709   79599.9582612864  -9585774352.21759 28302547195.6681  -19807136596.5434 -305910496.668656
79591.4731051894  3401.1232804516   52529359.4133139  -126479191.665267 76425077.4778451  -2563699.8428373
-9585920775.52777 52529288.3510008  1003916837759.99  -2454016116733.34 1501977763514.61  -42460326831.3218
28302900052.1238  -126478989.043282 -2454015575342.32 6017016899314.95  -3692050079960.62 101159202486.608
-19807349974.7679 76424938.7106429  1501977155911.81  -3692049404688.94 2270196092100.53  -60571139669.4392
-305903527.744471 -2563701.10409161 -42460406960.0488 101159421351.019  -60571285357.0572 2184863920.31107
```

The result I get in C is:

```
1398795243.74255  79184.33844201    -9594022229.12525 28322858223.2099  -19819644215.1338 -305583186.690388
79166.91917247    3402.48426033     52556628.829717   -126546466.939768 76466567.769084   -2564764.38775363
-9594334089.78616 52556515.9039231  1004461808180.58  -2455360323666.24 1502806633291.96  -42481639977.8112
28323609294.95    -126546129.049526 -2455359143404.21 6020330778543.35  -3694093433789.59  101211765648.895
-19820098170.0141 76466329.4304944  1502805309171.23  -3694091962863.6   2271455511686.72  -60603547743.7687
-305568392.855205 -2564768.40243798 -42481807759.1065 101212225714.588   -60603854784.616  2185698311.36118
```

The differences between the two are: (R-C)

```
-118562.671649933 415.6198192764    8247876.90765953  -20311027.5418015 12507618.5904007 -327309.978267968
424.5539327194    -1.3609798784     -27269.4164030999 67275.2745009959  -41490.291238904  1064.5449163299
8413314.25839043  -27227.552922301  -544970420.589966 1344206932.90039  -828869777.349854 21313146.4894028
-20709242.8262024 67140.0062440038  1343568061.89014  -3313879228.39941 2043353828.96973  -52563162.2870026
12748195.2462006  -41390.7198514938 -828153259.419922 2042558174.66016  -1259419586.19043 32408074.3294983
-335134.889266014 1067.29834637     21400799.0577011  -52804363.5690002 32569427.5587997  -834391.050109863
```

In order to check if there is a problem with the algorithm I used in C, I got he pseudoinverse in python with numpy.linalg.pinv() that uses "Singular Value Decomposition". The result is different from C and R.

```
1398224882.37767  81521.32618159    -9548319116.82994 28210636794.0452  -19750702778.4149 -307443670.558374
81576.67749763    3392.80756354     52367028.3401356  -126080750.377468 76180379.3995419  -2557069.77374461
-9547349936.09641 52367486.8455529  1000758728845.37  -2446264734953.02 1497217439225.67  -42331313003.6236
28208301799.8629  -126082060.163116 -2446268326785.52 5998001838415.43  -3680372478514.1  100842703532.378
-19749291055.22   76181277.4796568  1497221470187.79  -3680376958173.79 2263027785174.03  -60376849475.2803
-307489737.200422 -2557061.32729561 -42330783514.2789 100841257137.344  -60375886615.3659 2179570267.21681
```

- If the method and data used are the same what is causing the results
  to be different?.
- Which one of the results is the most accurate?

**Edit** I made a mistake, I have not put the matrix with all the digits to recreate the results, I've updated the question with the correct matrix.

Comment: The differences can be caused by the order in which optimizers have placed floating point calculation steps or applied rounding/scaling. Which one is the most precise is your job to determine. E.g. calculate the inverse by hand.

Comment: Do you provide a tolerance when calling 
pseudoinverse(m, tol) in R ?

Comment: The Moore Penrose inverse is not a method to calculate pseudo inverse matrices.  If a matrix is singular then it has an infinite number of pseudoinverses and the Moore Penrose inverse is a particular one of them.   How it is calculated is a separate question.

Comment: No, pseudoinverse() is called just with the matrix, the algorithm in R just uses that. In C I use 1E-15.

Comment: Package `MASS` also has a Moore-Penrose generalized inverse function `ginv`. With `tol=1e-15' it produces very different results from what you get.

Comment: @David, I am not sure if you were responding to me or to someone else in these comments but if you were responding to me the key point is that  the question refers to Moore Penrose as if it were a numerical method but it is not.  It is the definition of a particular pseduoinverse since there are an infinite number of pseudoinverse matrices to any singular matrix.  What numerical method  a particular function to calculate Moore Penrose inverses uses would be a separate question and is a matter of reading the documentation or source code.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I was responding to Glick. I think that would be the best way to check if the functions are doing the same thing to calculate the pseudoinverse.

Comment: @Bhas I also used `scipy.linalg.pinv` it produces the same result as with `numpy.linalg.pinv()`. The documentation says `scipy.linalg.pinv` uses a least-squares solver and not SVD like in `numpy.linalg.pinv()`.

Comment: As far as I can determine package `corpcor` does _not_ produce a pseudoinverse or Moore-Penrose inverse; the matrix it produces does not satisfy the four required conditions for a pseudoinverse. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse). You can check this easily using the four conditions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A [generalized inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_inverse) *A*<sup>g</sup>  for *A* should fulfill

*A*<sup>g</sup> *A* *A*<sup>g</sup> = *A*<sup>g</sup>

*A* *A*<sup>g</sup> *A* = *A*

(*A* *A*<sup>g</sup>)<sup>T</sup> = *A*<sup>g</sup> *A*

(*A*<sup>g</sup> *A*)<sup>T</sup> = *A* *A*<sup>g</sup>

For the given matrix the result of `corpcor::pseudoinverse` does not satisfy these properties, while the result of `MASS::ginv` does:

```r
check_pinv <- function(mat, fun, ...) {
    pinv <- fun(mat, ...)
    isTRUE(all.equal(mat %*% pinv %*% mat, mat)) &&
        isTRUE(all.equal(pinv %*% mat %*% pinv, pinv)) &&
        isTRUE(all.equal(pinv %*% mat, t(mat %*% pinv))) &&
        isTRUE(all.equal(mat %*% pinv, t(pinv %*% mat)))
}

mat <- matrix(c(                                                       
   1,                  0.920980394593472,  0.996160973582776,   0.996772980609752,   0.997372221594439, 0.999972797627027,
   0.920980394593472,  1,                  0.885601439824631,   0.88878682654952,    0.892173764646865, 0.923738536637407,
   0.996160973582776,  0.885601439824631,  1,                   0.999973383442349,   0.999885329646229, 0.99549326808266,
   0.996772980609752,  0.88878682654952,   0.999973383442349,   1,                   0.999969202115456, 0.996158288591094,
   0.997372221594439,  0.892173764646865,  0.999885329646229,   0.999969202115456,   1,                 0.996814694067663,
   0.999972797627027,  0.923738536637407,  0.99549326808266,    0.996158288591094,   0.996814694067663, 1), nrow = 6, ncol = 6)

check_pinv(mat, corpcor::pseudoinverse)
#> [1] FALSE
check_pinv(mat, MASS::ginv)
#> [1] TRUE
```

One important difference between the two functions is the default tolerance level that is used to determine if a singular value should be treated as zero. If one uses the value used in `MASS::ginv` (*i.e.* `sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)`) also for `corpcor::pseudoinverse`, the pseudo-inverse properties are fulfilled:

```r
check_pinv(mat, corpcor::pseudoinverse, max(svd(mat)$d) * sqrt(.Machine$double.eps))
#> [1] TRUE
```

Note that `max(svd(mat)$d) * sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)` has to be used since `corpcor::pseudoinverse` interprets the tolearance in an absolute sense, while `MASS::ginv` sees the tolerance as relative to the maximum singular value. With this tolerance level the pseudo-inverse matrices produced are identical.

```r
all.equal(corpcor::pseudoinverse(mat, max(svd(mat)$d) * sqrt(.Machine$double.eps)), 
          MASS::ginv(mat))
#> [1] TRUE
```

In python neither `numpy.linalg.pinv` nor `scipy.linalg.pinv` satisfy these properties:

```python
import numpy
mat = numpy.array([[1,            0.9209803946, 0.9961609736, 0.9967729806, 0.9973722216, 0.9999727976],
                   [0.9209803946, 1,            0.8856014398, 0.8887868265, 0.8921737646, 0.9237385366],
                   [0.9961609736, 0.8856014398, 1,            0.9999733834, 0.9998853296, 0.9954932681],
                   [0.9967729806, 0.8887868265, 0.9999733834, 1,            0.9999692021, 0.9961582886],
                   [0.9973722216, 0.8921737646, 0.9998853296, 0.9999692021, 1,            0.9968146941],
                   [0.9999727976, 0.9237385366, 0.9954932681, 0.9961582886, 0.9968146941, 1]])

pinv1 = numpy.linalg.pinv(mat)
print numpy.allclose(pinv1.dot(mat).dot(pinv1), pinv1)
# False
print numpy.allclose(mat.dot(pinv1).dot(mat), mat)
# True

from scipy import linalg
pinv2 = linalg.pinv(mat)
print numpy.allclose(pinv2.dot(mat).dot(pinv2), pinv2)
# False
print numpy.allclose(mat.dot(pinv2).dot(mat), mat)
# False

print numpy.allclose(pinv1, pinv2)
# True
```

**Note:** Matrix uses the original values. Results are unaffected, since only the smallest singular values show significant changes.

Again, if you use 1e-8 instead of the default 1e-15 as tolerance, these pseudo-inverse properties are fulfilled. The same holds for the C-version, which can be used from R together with RcppGSL.

Comment: Very nice. Interesting that the tolerance can have such an impact. What I do not understand is that the matrices generated by `ginv` and `pseudoinverse` are not identical even with the same tolerances. They are actually quite different.

Comment: I found the cause of the issue mentioned in the previous comment.

Comment: The `tol` argument for `corpcor` must be multiplied by `10` to get the same results as `ginv` in `MASS`. With the (standard)  `tol`  (as  given in the answer and used in `ginv`)  `fast.svd` accepts 4 singular values but `ginv` accepts only 3 singular values as satisfying the tolerance restriction.

Comment: @Bhas Thanks for the comment. The correct value is actually the maximum singular value, since `ginv` interprets the given tolerance as relative to that value, which is about 5.8 for this matrix. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: I updated the question with a matrix with more decimals, I tried your answer and I got the same results as you.

Comment: @Ralf Stubner. Using the largest singular value seems very expensive. You could also use the Frobenius norm of the matrix as mentioned [here](http://www.netlib.org/utk/people/JackDongarra/etemplates/node315.html)

Comment: @DavidMorocho Thanks, I have updated the R code in the answer. Since only the smallest singular values change significantly, the results are indeed the same.

Comment: @Bhas ACK, doing the full SVD just to determin the tolerance would be overkill in general. I am only doing it here to set exactly the same tolerance for both methods. For `ginv` there is no additional cost in using the largest singular value, since an SVD has to be done anyway.